# need help writing code that detects a keyboard capital letter key press with shift key for arduino with c/c++ programming

Tags: c++, arduino, keyboard, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

alright this is the code I got that tells me what key has been pressed.

```
#define CLOCK 6 //D-
#define DATA 7  //D+

const char keymap[][2] = {
  {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},                                                       //0
  {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {'`','~'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},                                                   //10
  {0,0}, {'q','Q'}, {'1','!'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {'z','Z'}, {'s','S'}, {'a','A'}, {'w','W'},                               //20
  {'2','@'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {'c','C'}, {'x','X'}, {'d','D'}, {'e','E'}, {'4','$'}, {'3','#'}, {0,0},                           //30
  {0,0}, {' ',' '}, {'v','V'}, {'f','F'}, {'t','T'}, {'r','R'}, {'5','%'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {'n','N'},                           //40
  {'b','B'}, {'h','H'}, {'g','G'}, {'y','Y'}, {'6','^'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {'m','M'}, {'j','J'},                           //50
  {'u','U'}, {'7','&'}, {'8','*'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {',','<'}, {'k','K'}, {'i','I'}, {'o','O'}, {'0',')'},                       //60
  {'9','('}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {'.','>'}, {'/','?'}, {'l','L'}, {';',':'}, {'p','P'}, {'-','_'}, {0,0},                           //70
  {0,0}, {0,0}, {'\'','\"'}, {0,0}, {'[','{'}, {'=','+'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},                                         //80
  {0,0}, {']','}'}, {0,0}, {'\\','|'}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},                                              //90
  {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {'1','!'}, {0,0}, {'4','$'}, {'7','&'}, {0,0},                                          //100
  {0,0}, {0,0}, {'0',')'}, {'.','>'}, {'2','@'}, {'5','%'}, {'6','^'}, {'8','*'}, {0,0}, {0,0},                               //110
  {0,0}, {'+','+'}, {'3','#'}, {'-','_'},{'*','*'}, {'9','('}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},                                    //120
  {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},                                                       //130
};
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(CLOCK, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  pinMode(DATA, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
uint8_t lastscan; // doesn't work

unsigned short detectKey(){
 unsigned short scanval = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i<11; i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(CLOCK));
    scanval |= digitalRead(DATA) << i;
    while(!digitalRead(CLOCK));
  }
  scanval >>= 1;
  scanval &= 0xFF;
  return scanval;
}

void loop() {
  bool shiftPressed= true //when the new code I need detects the shift held down;
  if(lastscan != 0xF0 && detectKey() != 0xF0)
  keymap[detectKey()][shiftPressed];
  lastscan = detectKey(); //this doesn't work to save the scancode to a variable
   /* switch(detectKey())
  {
    case 0x5A: //Enter
     Serial.println("Enter");
    break;
    case 0x66: //Backspace
      
    break;
    case 0x12:  //left shift
    while(detectKey() != 0xF0){
      shiftPressed = true;
    }
    shiftPressed = false;
  }
  */
}
```

Here is the Arduino Serial Monitor when I use the keyboard:

```
16:47:56.832 -> 1C //hit "a"
16:47:56.924 -> F0 //let go
16:47:56.924 -> 1C 
16:47:57.948 -> 1B //hit "s"
16:47:58.119 -> F0 //let go
16:47:58.119 -> 1B
16:48:02.119 -> 23 //held down "d"
16:48:02.722 -> 23
16:48:02.758 -> 23
16:48:02.758 -> F0 //let go
16:48:02.758 -> 23
```

as you can see, I would like to use F0 to tell the system that shift is being held down. the scancode for shift is 12 so shift would look like:

```
12
F0
12
```

so I would like to select from the capital letters in a seperate keymap array while I press another key at the same time as I'm pressing shift. I would then like to print the capital letter to serial.

Comment: Arduino is not C!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multidimensional array for you characters:

```
const char keymap[][2] = {
{0,0},{0,0},{'a','A'},
{'1','!'} //etc...
};
```

then to access the character, you would pass in a boolean for the second option `keymap[detectKey()][shiftPressed]`

Comment: ok I got the array fixed, I need to isolate the scancode as well as the key-release code, F0. I need to keep track of the shift key, and have the variable be true after the first scancode but false after f0. I need to do that at the same time it's detecting scancodes for keys. please see the edited question

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how your keyboard works. Does it continuously send the keys that are pressed or only sends them once? If its sent only once, then you want to make sure you don't miss it. Have it check for keypresses and only run any extra code when a new key is detected. If it detects shift pressed, set shiftPressed = true, then set it to false if a shift release comes in.

Comment: Right now I'm seeing you call "detectKey()" multiple times. If the keys are sent only once then obviously they'll only be picked up one time on the first "detectKey()". So call it once and set it to a variable, then just use that variable wherever you need it. Then update the variable on the next keypress.

Comment: so the serial connection part in the post goes over how the keyboard works. when you hold it down, it just keeps sending the key's scancode until you let go, then it sends the stop code, F0, to tell the computer the key had been released.

Comment: I tried setting detectKey() to a variable but I always need the variable to be up to date because of how quickly the keyboard sends scancodes. It's like that so detectKey updates each time it is referenced.

Comment: calling detectKey() once would be much more predictable than calling it a bunch of times. You want to be sure what you are getting and working with is the same thing. Also I noticed you declared lastscan as an unsigned byte, but you're returning an unsigned short which is 2 bytes. I would use the exact same data type to make things more predictable as well.

Comment: directKey() would pick up on a keypress, "a" would be 1C, F0, 1C. I need a method that tells me 2 keys being pressed at the same time, and when they are up and when they are down.

Comment: Idk what F0 is. I don't have your hardware to play with and figure out what is being sent. You're telling me that when you hit 'a' once it sends 3 keys?

Comment: a sends: 1C, the scancode, F0 which is the key-release hex for every key, and 1C again once after F0 for reasons unknown. If you hold a key down, it'll repeat 1C once every 250ms and that would send aaaaaaaaaaa until the keyboard sends F0 to let go. please see reddit page https://www.reddit.com/r/ArduinoHelp/comments/111hhh3/need_help_with_my_sweet_keyboard_program/